# ntopng and mysql dependency

Tags: mysql, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, upstart

I'm trying to setup `ntopng` (on raspbian) with persistent storage in MySQL. I've added the following line in ntopng.conf

```
--dump-flows=mysql;localhost;ntopng;flows;root;root
```

Upon boot, I find that ntopng has exited because it wasn't able to connect with the database

```
---snippet from /var/log/ntopng/ntopng.log------------

28/Dec/2016 09:50:03 [MySQLDB.cpp:573] Attempting to connect to MySQL for interface eth0...
28/Dec/2016 09:50:03 [MySQLDB.cpp:602] ERROR: Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)[localhost:root]
28/Dec/2016 09:50:03 [MySQLDB.cpp:79] ERROR: Unable to connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
28/Dec/2016 09:50:03 [main.cpp:279] ERROR: Unable to create database schema, quitting

----end of snippet--------------
```

But after booting, if I run `'sudo service ntopng restart'` I find that `ntopng` connects with MySQL and starts the service.

I'm guessing that during upstart, `ntopng` is being run before MySQL and fails to find an active daemon. Any way I can make sure that `ntopng` starts after MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there has been a version change since your question was asked, but I have been successful with placing the following line in /etc/ntopng/ntopng.conf (and I have used your settings for `<server>`, `<database>`, `<table>`, `<user>` and `<password>`)

```
-F "mysql;localhost;ntopng;flows;root;root"
```

From the docs it should be in the form;

```
-F "mysql;<server>;<database>;<table>;<user>;<password>"
```

This is obviously slightly different to what you have above (although `--dump-flows` should be replaceable for `-F`). It might be possible that the equals sign that you have mentioned should be a space and the latter part of the argument enclosed in speech-marks?